# Take screenshots for list of Urls using Puppeter.js

Tags: javascript, screenshot, puppeteer

Suppose I have list of Urls or full path to SVG files and Now I want to take screenshot for each of Urls, One by one.

Here is test code, I am using to take screenshots one by one, but it is not working as expected!

This code just start headless chrome page instance for all urls once and node.js throws this error

> (node:3412) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
>   leak detected. 11 lifecycleevent listeners added. Use
>   emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

But I wanted to take screenshots one by one.

```
'use strict';

const fs        = require('fs');
const glob      = require('glob');
const validUrl  = require("valid-url")
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const devices   = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');
const iPhone    = devices['iPhone 6'];

/**
 * Loading Application Config
 */
const inputUrl = 'http://www.google.com';

/**
 * Using Puppeteer.js
 */
console.log('-- Trying to Launch Puppeteer');
const browser = puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
}).then(function(browserObj)
{
    console.log('-- Trying to Open New Page');
    browserObj.newPage().then(function(pageObj)
    {
        async function closeHeadlesssChrome(browserObj) {
            console.log('-- Trying to Close Chome Headless Window');
            await browserObj.close();
        }

        async function setChromeViewport(pageObj) {
            console.log('-- Trying to Update page viewPort');
            await pageObj.setViewport({
                width: 1366,
                height: 738,
                deviceScaleFactor: 1,
                isMobile: false,
                hasTouch: false,
                isLandscape: false
            });
        }

        var takeScreenshot = async function(pageObj, srcUrl) {
            console.log('-- Trying to Load Web Page ' + srcUrl);
            await pageObj.goto(srcUrl);

            console.log('-- Trying to Take Screenshot');
            await pageObj.screenshot({
                path: srcUrl + '.png',
                clip: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    width: 795,
                    height: 1125
                }
            })
        }


        // Input or Source Url
        const inputUrl = "C:/Users/ssp/Music/BR PUBLIC INTER COLLEGE";
        var matchedFiles = [];

        // Check if given Url/Path exists
        if (fs.existsSync(inputUrl)) 
        {
            const inputUrlObj = fs.statSync(inputUrl);
            if (inputUrlObj.isDirectory()) 
            {
                matchedFiles = glob.GlobSync(inputUrl + '/**/*.svg').found;
            } 
            else if (inputUrlObj.isFile()) 
            {
                matchedFiles.push(inputUrl );
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            console.log('-- Input Url not exists')
            return closeHeadlesssChrome(browserObj);
        }

        setChromeViewport(pageObj);

        matchedFiles.map(function(srcUrl){
            takeScreenshot(pageObj, srcUrl);
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for..of` with `async-await` instead of `.map`. `.map` doesn't pause the execution but `await` will.

```
browserObj.newPage().then(async function(pageObj) { // <-- turn the main function into async function
 // ... many lines later
 for(let srcUrl of matchedFiles){
  await takeScreenshot(pageObj, srcUrl);
 }
```

Side-Note: Since all of your functions are independent from each other, maybe you can move them outside of the block and declare them before you call browserObj.newPage()

Here is the refactored code,pardon if something is wrong, but you get the idea.

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const glob = require("glob");
const validUrl = require("valid-url");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const devices = require("puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors");
const iPhone = devices["iPhone 6"];

/**
 * Loading Application Config
 */
const inputUrl = "http://www.google.com";

/**
 * Controller functions
 */

async function closeHeadlesssChrome(browserObj) {
  console.log("-- Trying to Close Chome Headless Window");
  await browserObj.close();
}

async function setChromeViewport(pageObj) {
  console.log("-- Trying to Update page viewPort");
  await pageObj.setViewport({
    width: 1366,
    height: 738,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    isMobile: false,
    hasTouch: false,
    isLandscape: false
  });
}

var takeScreenshot = async function(pageObj, srcUrl) {
  console.log("-- Trying to Load Web Page " + srcUrl);
  await pageObj.goto(srcUrl);

  console.log("-- Trying to Take Screenshot");
  await pageObj.screenshot({
    path: srcUrl + ".png",
    clip: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 795,
      height: 1125
    }
  });
};

function getURLList() {
  // Input or Source Url
  const inputUrl = "C:/Users/ssp/Music/BR PUBLIC INTER COLLEGE";
  var matchedFiles = [];

  // Check if given Url/Path exists
  if (fs.existsSync(inputUrl)) {
    const inputUrlObj = fs.statSync(inputUrl);
    if (inputUrlObj.isDirectory()) {
      matchedFiles = glob.GlobSync(inputUrl + "/**/*.svg").found;
    } else if (inputUrlObj.isFile()) {
      matchedFiles.push(inputUrl);
    }
    return matchedFiles;
  }
}

/**
 * Using Puppeteer.js
 */

(async () => {
  // get url list
  const matchedFiles = getURLList();
  if (!matchedFiles) {
    console.log("-- Input Url not exists");
    // if there is no url, then no need to even launch the browser and waste resources
    return;
  }

  console.log("-- Trying to Launch Puppeteer");
  const browserObj = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });

  console.log('-- Trying to Open New Page');
  const pageObj = await browserObj.newPage();

  console.log('-- Change Viewport');
  await setChromeViewport(pageObj);

  console.log('-- Run thru the url list');
  for (const srcUrl of matchedFiles) {
    await takeScreenshot(pageObj, srcUrl);
  }
})();
```